# opening a window in a target frame

Tags: java, php, html

I have a website and ran into an issue.

First of all the website is in dutch however the problem i have you don't have to understand dutch.

My website is [www.hobbysite.zz.mu/](http://www.hobbysite.zz.mu/)

When you click the login button it redirects you to a mybb forum login (this is correct)
next part is the tricky part for me.

when you click the login button there it should run this script:

```
 <html> <head>

     <script language="Javascript">
         function trigger(){ 
     document.php-form.submit(); 
     document.htm-form.submit(); }

     </script> </head>


 <body onload="trigger();">
     <form name="php-form" action="http://hobbysite.zz.mu/top.html" target="_topframe">
     <form name="htm-form" action="http://hobbysite.zz.mu/Main/main.html" target="mainframe">
 </body>
```

Problem is however that its not doing the first option and chance the "cloud" set.

my first cloudset is[www.hobbysite.zz.mu/top1.html](http://www.hobbysite.zz.mu/top1.html) and it should chance in the target frame topframe to [hobbysite.zz.mu/top.html](http://hobbysite.zz.mu/top.html)

thanks in advance

Comment: U are using _topframe as target while the name of that frame is 'topframe'. You should use 'target="topframe"'.

Comment: I've changed it but still it aint working.

Comment: I did both options and my first cloudset does disapear however my second cloudset does not show up

Comment: It seems that once you click the login button on the mybb forum, all the target commands are beeing ignored

Comment: Allright your code is uploaded however it still does not do the trick my topframe does not change the cloudset nor does this script open main.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to submit two forms you could change the location of the frames. Try this code:

```
<html><head>
<script>
function trigger() {
    top.frames["topFrame"].location.href="http://hobbysite.zz.mu/top.html";
    top.frames["mainFrame"].location.href="http://hobbysite.zz.mu/Main/main.html";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="trigger();"> 
</body></html>
```

Comment: Allright your code is uploaded however it still does not do the trick my topframe does not change the cloudset nor does this script open main.html

Comment: It seems that the target frame is not working, or the site wont read it

Comment: Are you sure the function is executed when you expect it to. If so, do you get any errors or something in your console?